# In mmm-mode can you have several classes for the same mode?

Tags: minor-mode, mmm-mode

In my code I have the following to delimit regions that initiate/end `whatevz-mode`:

```
(require 'mmm-mode)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)

(mmm-add-classes
  '((whatevz
          :submode whatevz-mode
          :front ".*whatevz\(\"\"\""
          :back ".*\"\"\"\)")))

(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'whatevz-mode nil 'whatevz)
```

I want to add several possible snippets that delimit `whatevz-mode` (The above only shows `whatevz("""`). Do I have to add that to the `add-classes`   above - creating a much more advanced regex - or can I call `mmm-add-classes` again with another simple regex?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the latter is possible. You can have two different add-classes for the same embedded language, but you must name them differently.